# firebase twitter login error : auth/invalid-credential

Tags: javascript, firebase, twitter

I'm going to put a firebase-based Twitter login on a web page.
As shown in Docs, we created an app on the Twitter developer portal, put the app key and app secret in the firebase column, respectively, and added the firebase's callback URL to the Twitter app.

When you try to run by pressing the login button, a rare appears with the following error code.
auth/invalid-credential
The supplied auth credential is malformed or has expired.

Do you happen to know what I did wrong? Can I also know the solution?
JavaScript was used, and under the same conditions, Facebook and Google can log in well and retrieve user information.

Someone help me why Twitter is the only thing like this... I am desperate!
Below, I put my Twitter login code and other screenshots together in case I need it.

```
$(document).on('click', '#twiter', function () {
var provider = new firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider();
firebase.auth().useDeviceLanguage();
firebase
    .auth()
    .signInWithPopup(provider)
    .then((res) => {
        /** @type {firebase.auth.OAuthCredential} */
        var token = result.credential.accessToken;
        var user = result.user;

        console.log(token)
        console.log(user)
        // ...
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
        console.log(error.code)
        console.log(error.message)
    });
```

});

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKeYF.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UST2q.png)

Comment: Did you found a solution? I have the same issue

Comment: Hi.
The problem was confirmed as a phenomenon that occurs because when you log in to Twitter, you log in to Twitter on the web itself. In other words, it was necessary to log out of Twitter itself to log in to another Twitter account. Other than this, I haven't found a solution yet...

Comment: I found a solution. You need apply for Twitter "ELEVATED ACCESS" to access "Login to Twitter" for Firebase auth.